# Can't access default controller after installing Codeigniter HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I use Codeigniter 3.1.0 and I just installed modular HMVC in it. 
Here is brief the file hierarchy:

```
-application
--controllers (default controllers folder non hmvc)
---hello_one.php
--modules
---hello_two
----controllers
-----hello_two.php
----models
----views
```

After installing HMVC modular I can access hello_two controller but I can't access hello_one default (non HMVC) controller anymore unless I extend MX_Controller extends CI_Controller in MX Folder.

why is it? does installation gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to make sure you have the first letter ONLY of file and class name upper case for controllers, models, libraries

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#class-and-method-naming

hello_one.php

hello_two.php

Change to

Hello_one.php

Hello_two.php

Routes

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home_one';
```

If HMVC for default controller

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'hello_two/home_two/index';
$route['default_controller'] = 'module/controller/function';
```